# Join four columns into one according to each row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, google-sheets-query

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P
```

If I chose to join the columns I would `={A1:A;B1:B;C1:C;D1:D}` but it would look like this:

```
A
E
I
M
B
F
J
N
... and so on
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
... and so on
```

How to proceed in this case?

Note: It may happen that some of the columns are not complete in data, some may have more values than the others, but I still want to continue following this same pattern. Example:

```
A B   D
E   G H
I J K L
M N O P
```

Result:

```
A
B
D
E
G
H
... and so on
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your data and desired output when you have the stated condition *that some of the columns are not complete in data*. Also, what have you tried and where have you run into problems. And also, what version of Excel.

Comment: Ah, I see you have removed Excel from your list of tags, so I won't bother further with an Excel solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:D),, 9^9))
```

[image: 0]

then:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:D),,9^9)),,9^9), " "))
```

[image: 0]