# Stack multiple columns into one without ignore blank cells

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, google-sheets-query

For a stack of several columns and filtering the blank cells, @player0 told me to do it as follows:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60028660/11462274

But I came across the need for the blank cells not to be ignored, because I'm going to use a script on four different spreadsheets, and each one of them will send data to the first blank row of the columns, so it may happen that some columns have more data than the others and as I am going to record values manually in the column on the side, if I change the positions it will mess up what I record manually.

:

```
A B C D
E F G H
  J K L
  N
```

Expected result:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H

J
K
L

N
```

These blank spaces will be necessary so that when new data is recorded in the columns, the old ones do not change position, remain in the same place where they are.

Would it be possible to do that?

> Note: I have already looked in some places saying that if I do this,
>   the spreadsheet would be immense because of the number of blank lines
>   that it would take into account. I imagine that it would be necessary
>   only the blank cells until the last line that has data at the moment,
>   the rest would not be necessary.
>
> But I was unable to adjust to make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is so simple it hurts, but you can use `=FLATTEN(A1:D)`

Yes, that easy.

Apparently, Google never documented this `FLATTEN` function, but it works PERFECTLY for what you want and what I've needed as well.

Hope someone finds this even though it's been answered, I know I've needed it forever haha.

Comment: Hi mate! Where did you find this function? I was intrigued and would like to know if by chance there may be more others that are hidden in the list and try to understand why they are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to achieve the following situation.

  - From

    ```
    A B C D
    E F G H
      J K L
      N
    ```
  - To

    ```
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E
    F
    G
    H

    J
    K
    L

    N
    ```
- In above case, you want to use only the values from `A` to `N`. You don't want to include the empty values after the value of `N`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A1:D,"#"),",+#",","),",",,FALSE))
```

1. Join the values of "A1:D" using `TEXTJOIN()`.
2. Remove the empty values after the last character using `REGEXREPLACE()`.
3. Split the value using `SPLIT()` from a string to an array.
4. Transpose the array using `TRANSPOSE()`.

Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is exactly i need. Thanks mate!

Comment: Mate, this message appeared: The textual result of TEXTJOIN exceeds the limit of 50000 characters. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. In that case, how about the following workarounds? 1. Reduce the data by splitting. 2. Use Google Apps Script.

Comment: I tried to decrease by doing A1 to D50, A51 to D100, A101 to D150 ... But when I joined by ```=ARRAYFORMULA({XX; XX; XX})``` blank lines appeared in the divisions, I tried to remove them by ```=QUERY("Where Col1 is not null")```, but if I do that those blank lines that I need will disappear. The second option for the app script unfortunately I don't know how to create a formula like that over there. If you can help me, I can even share my spreadsheet if necessary or create a new question to give you more points. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, can I ask you about the reason that you cannot achieve this using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Unfortunately the only things I know how to create through the app script are common functions that are learned when recording macros. Create a script with this functionality as I need it I can't do it.

Comment: Tanaike, thank you very much ... I remembered a way to solve the problem of the extra line, all I had to do was add an ARRAYCONSTRAIN with a maximum of 200 lines and 1 column. In that way the additional line disappeared. Everything worked! Thank you!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

you can build on it like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A:D="", CHAR(9), A:D)),,9^9)),,9^9), " ")), ROWS(A:A), 1))
```

[image: 0]